# Help on MySQL joins

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-key

I'm building a system to monitor currency prices. Part of my database structure looks like this:

[image: currency monitor db]

My system is trying to pull the api ticker for each exchange with this query:

```
SELECT distinct E.exchange_id, E.exchange_name, P.pair_id, P.pair_name,T.pair_ticker           
FROM exchange as E
left Join exchange_has_currency_pairs as PE on E.exchange_id = PE.exchange_exchange_id
left Join currency_pairs as P on PE.currency_pairs_pair_id = P.pair_id
left join currency_pairs_ticker as T on P.pair_id = T.currency_ticker_id
order by E.exchange_name desc
```

The query is returning all the results, but the pair_ticker isn't matching the pair name or corresponding exchange in all the cases. Should there be another n:m on currency_pairs to currency_pairs_ticker or are my joins not correct?

Thanks for any input.

EDIT
Sample out put from bellow answer

```
+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| exchange_id | exchange_name | pair_id | pair_name | pair_ticker                                                                |
+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           4 | bitstamp      |       1 | btc_usd   | https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker                                 |
|           4 | bitstamp      |       1 | btc_usd   | https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=USD              |
|           4 | bitstamp      |       1 | btc_usd   | https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/                                   |
|           4 | bitstamp      |       1 | btc_usd   | http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=2   |
|           1 | btc-e         |       1 | btc_usd   | https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker                                 |
|           1 | btc-e         |       1 | btc_usd   | https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=USD              |
|           1 | btc-e         |       1 | btc_usd   | https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/                                   |
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your currency_pairs_ticker is joining the wrong fields.

your existing join:

```
left join currency_pairs_ticker as T on P.pair_id = T.currency_ticker_id
```

corrected join:

```
left join currency_pairs_ticker as T on P.pair_id = T.currency_pairs_pair_id
```

The complete sql

```
SELECT distinct E.exchange_id, E.exchange_name, P.pair_id,    P.pair_name,T.pair_ticker           
FROM exchange as E
left Join exchange_has_currency_pairs as PE on E.exchange_id = PE.exchange_exchange_id
left Join currency_pairs as P on PE.currency_pairs_pair_id = P.pair_id
left join currency_pairs_ticker as T on P.pair_id = T.currency_pairs_pair_id
order by E.exchange_name desc
```

Comment: Good catch. And I think the `DISTINCT` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your input i ran the query through the data set but the joins don't seem to match the correct ticket api url with the currency pair or exchange.

I added a sample out put above to the original question above as there is not enough space here

I set P.pair_id = T.currency_pairs_pair_id as T.currency_pairs_pair_id is the P.pair_id foreign key to match the results